# Does my practice is good for helper testing with rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I write a engine to add some helper methods just for learning.

```
module SharpAssets
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer "sharp_asssets.assets_precompile" do |app|
      ActionView::Base.send(:include, SharpAssets::Helper)
    end
  end

  module Helper
    def hi_engine
      "test"
    end
  end
end
```

and my test case is :

```
require 'test_helper'

class SharpAssetsTest < ActionView::TestCase
  include SharpAssets::Helper  
  test "should work" do
    assert_equal "test", hi_engine
  end
end
```

I want to know is this way a good practice ?

And another question is why I can include `SharpAssets::Helper` in my test case ? I don't require any files from lib folder.